# Intersection of a ring class field of a quadratic field K with the cyclotomic extension of K

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratic field. Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_f=\mathbf{Z}+f\mathcal{O}_K$ be the unique order of $K$ of index $f$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $H_f^{ring}$ denote the ring class field in the narrow sense
(so we allow ramification at infinite real places of $K$, if such places exist)
associated to the order $\mathcal{O}_f$. For a number field $L$ let us denote
by $\mu(L)$ the group of roots of unity of $L$. For an integer $n\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geq 2}$ we let $\mu_n$ be the group of $n$-th roots of unity
and $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity. An (not so trivial) exercise in class field theory shows that $\mu(K_f^{ring})\subseteq \mu_{12}$. Let us denote by $K^{gen}$ the genus field in the narrow sense of $K$. Recall that the genus field $M^{gen}$ (in the narrow sense) of an abelian extension $M$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ is the maximal unramified extension $M^{gen}$ over $M$ (at all finite places of $M$) which is abelian over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Note that $H_K=K_{1}^{ring}$ corresponds to the Hilbert class field, in the narrow sense, of $K$. We obviously have $K_{f}^{ring}\supseteq H_K\supseteq K^{gen}$. Let $d$ be the discriminant of $K$. We also have $K^{gen}\subseteq K(\zeta_d)$. Let $L=K(\zeta_n:n\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geq 2})$.

So this begs the following question:

**Q** Do we always have that $K_{f}^{ring}\cap L\subseteq K^{gen}(\mu_{12})$ ?

P.S. Note that $K^{gen}(\mu_{12})\subseteq K(\mu_m)$ where $m=lcm(d,12)$.

P.S.S. An explicit description of the genus field: In genreral, if $k$ is an abelian extension over $\mathbf{Q}$, we have $k\subseteq\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$
for some $m$. We may associate to $k$ a subgroup $X_k$ of the Pontryagin dual of $(\mathbf{Z}/m\mathbf{Z})^{\times}$, which we denote by $X_m$. Note that $X_m$ has a natural direct sum decomposition with respect to the inertia subgroups of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$; which are in correspondence with the primes $p|m$. This simply corresponds to the usual decomposition of a Dirichlet charcter via the Chinese remainder theorem for the prime powers dividing $m$. 
It is a simple exercise to show that the "cartesian closure" of the subgroup $X_k$ (with respect to this direct sum decomposition of $X_m$) corresponds to $k^{gen}$. So in the case where $k$ is quadratic over $\mathbf{Q}$, this implies that $k^{gen}$ is a multiquadratic extension over $k$. See the [wikepedia page on genus fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_field) for an explicit description of $k^{gen}$ when $k$ is quadratic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. I'll only focus on imaginary quadratic fields since they are easier to deal with than real ones. Great reference for all this theory is Cox's book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*.

So let $K$ be imagimary, thus $d<0$, and let $D=f^2d$. Since $L=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, the field $K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L$ is the maximal subfield of $K_f^{\text{ring}}$ which is abelian over $\mathbb{Q}$. We have $\operatorname{Gal}(K_f^{\text{ring}}/K)\cong C(D)$, where $C(D)$ is the group of classes of primitive positive definite binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$, and $G:=\operatorname{Gal}(K_f^{\text{ring}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the generalized dihedral group $C(D)\rtimes\{\pm1\}$ (which means that $-1$ acts on $C(D)$ as inverse). 
Under this isomorphism $[G,G]$ corresponds to $C(D)^2\times\{1\}$. Since $\operatorname{Gal}(K_f^{\text{ring}}/K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L)=[G,G]$, we get $[K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L:K]=[C(D):C(D)^2]$.

Let $r$ be the number of odd primes dividing $D$. We define number $\mu$ in the following way: if $D$ is odd then $\mu=r$, and if $D=-4n$ is even then
$$\mu=
\begin{cases}
r&\text{if }n\equiv3\pmod4,\\
r+1&\text{if }n\equiv1,2\pmod4,\\
r+1&\text{if }n\equiv4\pmod8,\\
r+2&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod8.\\
\end{cases}$$
Gauss proved that $[C(D):C(D)^2]=2^{\mu-1}$, so we get $[K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L:K]=2^{\mu-1}$ and $[K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L:\mathbb{Q}]=2^\mu$. In fact we can describe $K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L$ explicitly. Let $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ be odd primes dividing $D$ and let $p^*=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$. If $D$ is odd then $K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*})$, and if $D$ is even then 
$$K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*})&\text{if }n\equiv3\pmod4,\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*},i)&\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod4,\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*},\sqrt{-2})&\text{if }n\equiv2\pmod8,\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*},\sqrt{2})&\text{if }n\equiv6\pmod8,\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*},i)&\text{if }n\equiv4\pmod8,\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1^*},\ldots,\sqrt{p_r^*},i,\sqrt{2})&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod8.
\end{cases}$$

Since $K^{\text{gen}}=K_1^{\text{ring}}\cap L$, by applying the previous formula with $f=1$ we get $[K^{\text{gen}}:\mathbb{Q}]=2^{\mu'}$, where $\mu'$ is defined same as $\mu$ with $d$ in place of $D$. Thus $[K^{\text{gen}}(\zeta_{12}):\mathbb{Q}]\le[K^{\text{gen}}:\mathbb{Q}]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12}):\mathbb{Q}]= 2^{\mu'}\cdot\varphi(12)=2^{\mu'+2}$. In particular $[K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L:\mathbb{Q}]$ can be arbitrarily much larger than $[K^{\text{gen}}(\zeta_{12}):\mathbb{Q}]$ (if $f$ is divisible by lot of primes that don't divide $d$). However even if $[K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L:\mathbb{Q}]\le[K^{\text{gen}}(\zeta_{12}):\mathbb{Q}]$ that still doesn't imply $K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L\subseteq K^{\text{gen}}(\zeta_{12})$. For example take $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $f=8$. Then $K_f^{\text{ring}}=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $K_f^{\text{ring}}\cap L=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ but $K^{\text{gen}}(\zeta_{12})=K(\zeta_{12})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$.

Comment: Dear Jarek, many thanks for the nice answer.